# Outlook View Control for Office 2010 64-bit

Tags: c#, com, 64-bit, office-2010

In our application we use the OVC for showing the Outlook Calendar. As our customers uses different versions of Office, we provide different versions for O2003, O2007 and O2010.

In O2010, the OVC will not work in 64 bit mode. When trying to run, you get a 'Class not registered' message.

So I made a 64-bits virtual machine with Office 2010 64 bit on it and installed Visual Studio to see if i could add the OVC to an C# testproject. Then I find out that the COM control (outlctl) isn't registered, and can't be registered either.

On [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-office-HA010369476.aspx?CTT=1) I saw the following text:

> What is in the 32-bit version of
>   Office but is not included in the
>   64-bit version of Office?
>
> ActiveX controls library, ComCtl 
>   This library contains ActiveX controls
>   that are used to build solutions. It
>   is most commonly used in the following
>   Microsoft Office programs: Access,
>   Excel, and Word.

So, will this be possible in the future? Or is there any other way to show a calendar as an ActiveX component?

Thanks in advance,

Rutger